# Как сделать разноцветными четные и нечетные строки таблицы jsp?

Tags: jsp, java, mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы четные строки таблицы были одного цвета, а нечетные - другого цвета в вот этом примере:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<html>
<t:template>
    <body>
    <c:if test="${!empty categoryList}">
        <table class="category-table">
            <tr><th colspan="5"><span class= "users-label">
            <spring:message code="label.categories"/></span></th></tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="lower"><spring:message code="label.category.name"/></th>
                <td class="addLink" colspan="2"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/category/add" title="Add Category">
                    <spring:message code="label.addCategory" /></a></td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="category">
                    <tr class="lines">
                    <td>${category.name}</td>
                    <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/category/edit/${category.id}">
                        <spring:message code="label.edit" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/category/delete/${category.id}">
                        <spring:message code="label.delete" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if>
       </body>
</t:template>
</html>
```

Так как здесь используется цикл, то все строки получаются одного цвета.
P. S. Данные хранятся в базе mysql.

Comment: А чем Вас css не устраивает?

Comment: @Loff, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вам совет, учитесь гуглить! Это один из самых важнейших скиллов в программировании да и вообще в жизни:)

Если вы используете css3, то красивое решение вот [Псевдокласс :nth-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child).

Если хотите, чтобы все браузеры поддерживали, то в цикле на четные и нечетные вешаете разные css классы, ну и, соответственно, прописываете их в таблице стилей.

PS: Данные, которые хранятся в базе mysql, тут вообще ни при чем.)